# How to limit the number of Mono waiting for completion?

Tags: java, project-reactor

In Project Reactor I have a set number of requests to be made in the format of Mono. In order to not overwhelm the target service, I need to limit the number of requests to at most X per second and more than that ensure that I have a maximum of N pending requests waiting for completion.

The time limiting part was easy tranforming a list of Monos in a Flux and using the function `Flux#delayElement` but I can't figure the second requisite.

How can I limit the number of Mono waiting for completion?

Comment: What about using a Semaphore?

Comment: resilience4j has features which are not in project reactor like circuit-breaker, rate limiter. Please explore rate limiter functionality which might help how to restrict the calling rate . https://github.com/resilience4j/resilience4j#ratelimiter